# Problemas com SSH: IP sendo banido após x logins bem-sucedidos consecutivos

Tags: ssh, nagios

Estou tendo um pequeno problema com o SSH de um dos servidores da empresa. O problema é que estou utilizando um software de monitoramento chamado Nagios, e como a utilização de algum outro modo de checagem, como o NRPE, exige a instalação de diversos pacotes que prefiro não instalar, já que o servidor é dedicado, resolvi utilizar checagem por SSH. Criei uma chave de acesso, pro próprio Nagios fazer o acesso por SSH e coletar as informações e deu tudo certo. Agora que o problema aparece. Toda vez que ativo as checagens nesse servidor, ele checa tudo normal, mas quando vai fazer a sexta checagem consecutiva, o meu IP é banido e dá timeout, então tenho que ir em outro servidor, pular pra ele e desbanir meu IP, mas assim que o Nagios vai fazer as checagens o IP já é banido novamente.

Vejam bem, o problema não é na chave de acesso que criei, pois ela funciona normalmente, inclusive quando testo com o comando abaixo:

```
sudo -u nagios ssh nagios@servidor
```

Ou com o próprio plugin do Nagios:

```
sudo -u nagios ./check_by_ssh -l nagios -H <ip-do-servidor> -C "<comando>"
```

A questão é a quantidade de vezes que logo. Pelo que notei, após 5 logins consecutivos, no sexto ele já bane meu IP.

Para me certificar que não era algo exclusivo apenas no Nagios, fiz 5 acessos consecutivos via terminal no servidor e no sexto bloqueou também. A resposta no sexto acesso é essa:

```
ssh: connect to host <server>.<domain> port <port-number>: Connection timed out
```

Há alguma configuração do SSH, talvez em /etc/ssh/sshd_config ou /etc/ssh/ssh_config, que permita configurar o número permitido de logins bem-sucedidos consecutivos? Algo como o maxretry e bantime?

Comment: Não conheço nenhuma restrição deste tipo do SSHD. Teria como postar as mensagens do log do SSHD? Principalmente as de desconexão e as de erro.

Comment: @ThiagoMartins, acredito que este link pode lhe ajudar: http://z9.io/2008/12/10/how-to-fix-ssh-timeout-problems/

Answer (score 2):

Olá, gostaria de informar que o problema foi resolvido.

O Fail2ban contava os acessos bem sucedidos junto com os acessos mal sucedidos, porque no arquivo `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf` havia um *failregex* que deveria ser comentado:

```
^%(__prefix_line)sAddress <HOST> .* POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!*\s*$
```

e entrava para o contador porque essa frase aparecia sempre no login, informando que não é possível fazer mapeamento reverso do IP. Comentei e o problema foi solucionado.